# Thermodynamics: What is $dE/(dV)|_T$?

Tags: thermodynamics

Does 
$$
\left.\frac{\partial {\cal E}}{\partial\rho}\right|_T=?\;\;
{\rm or} \;\;
\left.\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}\right|_T=?
$$
where $E$ is energy, ${\cal E}$ is energy density, $V$ is volume, $\rho$ is (mass) density have a name? Is there a simple relation ship to "standard" quantities, like the speed of sound, volume expansion coefficients, or specific heats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$dE = T\,dS-P\,dV$$
$$\begin{align*}\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}\right)_T&=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T-P \\
&=T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V-P \\
&=-T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P-P \\
&=T\alpha_V\kappa-P
\end{align*}$$
where $\alpha_V$ is the volumetric coefficient of linear expansion and $\kappa$ is the bulk modulus. To convert the partial derivatives, I used a [Maxwell relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations) and then the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule).

Comment: Thanks. One small thing: In the third equality $(\partial V)/(\partial P)$ is presumable upside down.